# Suppress the missing font warning with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot and get this warning everytime I generate a graph:

> Could not find/open font when opening font "arial", using internal non-scalable font

Is there a way to suppress the warning?

Comment: Do you get this error using the `gd` terminals?  (e.g. `png`, `jpeg`, `gif`, ...)?  Does it happen with other terminals as well?

Comment: Yes, I am generating a png file. Not sure about the other formats.

Comment: What version of gnuplot are you using?  Do you have the `pngcairo` terminal available?  If you do, try using that terminal.  You might get nicer looking images as a side benefit :)

Comment: Okay, I need to read about what a terminal is first.

Comment: Terminals are what control the output driver and are set by the `set terminal` command (often abbreviated to `set term`):  For example, `set term postscript` or `set terminal png` or `set terminal pngcairo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning is generated by the `gd` backend I believe.  Suppressing it might be a little tricky (you could try redirecting `stderr` of the gnuplot process), but `gnuplot` seems to like to write useful things to `stderr`, so I don't advise that ... and the builtin (non-scalable) font looks like garbage.  The easiest fix is to see if your gnuplot was built with `pango-cairo` support.  Just try:

```
set term pngcairo
```

instead of:

```
set term png
```

In this case, the font subsystem of `cairo` will take over rather than of `gd`.  As a side bonus, I've found that I'm much happier with the `cairo` plots.

If that's not an option, you can download/find a suitable font and put it in a directory somewhere.  Then you can set an environment variable `GDFONTPATH` to point to that directory.  For example, find a truetype font that looks like `Arial` and put it in `~/fonts/arial.ttf`.  Then set your environment `export GDFONTPATH=${HOME}/fonts` and all should work.

If you're willing to live with the ugly font that gd provides, you can use the builtin fonts explicitly:

```
set term png tiny
```

or:

```
set term png large
```

See `help fonts gd` for more information.